# Oracle SQL Trigger Syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger that checks if the faculty member to be added to the assigned table will is already on the qualified table for a specified class. Perhaps this is a tedious method. Nevertheless, I'd still like to know what I'm doing wrong. The following is my code with created the created tables and the trigger being the last part of the code:

CODE:

```
CREATE TABLE Faculty (
  FId varchar(10),
  FName varchar(20),
  CONSTRAINT Faculty_ID_pk PRIMARY KEY(FId)
);

CREATE TABLE Course (
  CId varchar(10),
  CName varchar(20),
  CONSTRAINT Course_ID_pk PRIMARY KEY(CId)
);

CREATE TABLE Qualify (
  QDate DATE,
  FId varchar(10),
  CId varchar(10),
  CONSTRAINT Qualifying_date CHECK(QDate >= TO_DATE('2020-08-24', 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
  CONSTRAINT Qualify_FID_fk FOREIGN KEY(FId) REFERENCES Faculty(FId),
  CONSTRAINT Qualify_CID_fk FOREIGN KEY(CId) REFERENCES Course(CId)
);

CREATE TABLE Assign (
  ADate DATE,
  FId varchar(10),
  CId varchar(10),
  CONSTRAINT Qualifying_check CHECK(ADate > TO_DATE('2020-08-24', 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
  CONSTRAINT Assign_FID_fk FOREIGN KEY(FId) REFERENCES Faculty(FId),
  CONSTRAINT Assign_CID_fk FOREIGN KEY(CId) REFERENCES Course(CId)
);



CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Check_If_Qualified
   BEFORE INSERT ON Assign
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   v_facNum number;
BEGIN
   SELECT f.FId
      into v_facNum
      from Faculty f
      where f.facnum = :new.fid;
END;
```

However, I keep receiving an error saying:

Error at line 7: PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'F' reference is out of scope

5. v_facNum number;
6. BEGIN
7. SELECT f.FId
8. into v_facNum
9. from Faculty f

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like this (sample tables are really just a *sample*; they are here to make the trigger compile):

```
SQL> create table assign (fid number);

Table created.

SQL> create table faculty (facnum number, fid number);

Table created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Check_If_Qualified
  2    BEFORE INSERT ON Assign
  3    FOR EACH ROW
  4  DECLARE
  5    v_facNum number;
  6  BEGIN
  7     SELECT f.FId
  8       into v_facNum
  9       from Faculty f
 10       where f.facnum = :new.fid;
 11
 12    -- now do something with v_facNum
 13  END;
 14  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Okay, the error I am now getting is:

"subprogram or cursor 'F' reference is out of scope"

Perhaps I should mention that I'm quite new to SQL. What does this error mean? Is it because 'F' is undefined?

Comment: You did something wrong; I edited code I previously posted by creating those tables and - trigger compiles successfully. If your code doesn't work, please, edit your original message and post copy/paste of your SQL*Plus session (just like I did) so that we could see what you exactly did and how Oracle responded.

Comment: Okay, I have updated the code with how I created the tables. Perhaps I should have mentioned the tables contain constraints upon creation. Could that be the problem? Do I need to remove all predefined constraints from the tables in order to create triggers for them?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out! When I replaced 'f' with the table name 'Faculty', and changed f.facnum to Faculty.FId, it worked. Thanks a lot for your help, though! Now, I can check if the faculty number exists on the qualified table before I insert. If not, I can halt the insert because if a faculty member is not qualified to teach a class, the trigger needs to ensure they are not assigned to teach it.

Comment: I'm glad you made it work; thank you for letting us know!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of issues in your code. You can check the count of records into `FACULTY` table and use that count for whatever logic you want.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHECK_IF_QUALIFIED 
    BEFORE INSERT ON ASSIGN
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    CNT   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1)
      INTO CNT
      FROM FACULTY
     WHERE FACNUM = :NEW.FID;
END;
/
```

Comment: I'm unsure if that worked because now it says:

"SQL Statement ignored"

Does the count return the first record from the FACULTY table?